# Как выполнить обращение к TLS протоколу?

Tags: ssl, curl, php, https, сервер

Здравствуйте!

Собственно сам код:

```
$data = '{"params": ["testing_true", "bb4238e7-8f6d-4b2e-9ea4-43791bfb72df"], "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "gate.check", "id": 27034}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "tls://site.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 4928); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,   array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)                                                                       
));       

$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_error($ch));

var_dump(curl_errno($ch));

echo($output) . PHP_EOL;

curl_close($ch);
```

При таком обращении получаю

```
Protocol tls not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Здесь есть пример обращения к TLS, как его подружить с cURL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153206/how-to-make-tls-connection-from-php-in-web-server-and-safely/3153717#3153717

Answer (score 1):

Через https с надстройкой пробовали?

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

Comment: да, сервер возвращает пустой ответ